# Should query with "AND" operator in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to write a query inside should such that when both matches the document then i will boost the score by 2 but when any one of them or none of them matches i do not want any boost my code is given below now can anyone please tell me how should i write my "Should" query so that i can do my work.

```
query: {
                bool: {
                  must: {
                    query_string: {
                      query: shop_search,
                      fields: ['shop_name'],
                      boost: 3.0
                    }
                  }, should: [
                    {
                      term : { 'address.area2' : search_area2 }
                    },
                    {
                      term : { "address.area1" : search_area1 }
                    }
                  ], "boost": 2.0
                } 
              }
```

Answer (score 5):

Nest another boolean query inside your should clause:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "query_string": {
                "query": shop_search,
                "fields": ["shop_name"],
                "boost": 3.0
            }
        },
        "should": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "address.area2": search_area2
                    }
                }, {
                    "term": {
                        "address.area1": search_area1
                    }
                }],
                "boost": 2.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please write where i can specify boost also ?? i mean just type the query part ??

Comment: Sorry, I had it in the wrong place (now fixed).  I think your goal is that when both area1 AND area2 match to boost the outer query score by 2.   So you want the inner-bool to have a boost of 2.0 when matched.

Comment: like this ??     should: {
                            bool: {
                              must: [
                                {
                                  term : { 'address.area2' : "Area" }
                                },
                                {
                                  term : { "address.area1" : "hitefield" }
                                }
                              ]
                            }, "boost": 2.0
                         }

Comment: sorry but it's not working this is boosting even if only one area match  but i want to boost only when both area's matches

Comment: Run it with `"explain":true`.  You should see the match and score contribution coming only from `shop_name`.

Comment: actually problem is that it is not working for both case when one matches it also increments the score that is where the problem is coming